# Store path of a photo in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I followed this tutorial on how to upload a photo in a codeigniter folder:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Can anybody tell me how can I store the path of the photo I just uploaded in my db?
Let's say have table called `photo_paths`
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you have an Images table.

Configure the file upload as follows:

```
 $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
 $config['max_size']    = '1000000';
 $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
 $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
 $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Then on successful upload insert the file information into the database.

```
$insert_data = array(
'id_fk' => $this->input->post('page_id'),
'imgfilename' => $upload_info['file_name'],
'imgfilepath' => $upload_info['file_path']
);
$this->db->insert('images', $insert_data);
```

$upload info is retrived from the file_uploader class on successful upload using the following:

```
$upload_info = $this->upload->data();
```

If you want to see exactly what is returned:

```
echo var_dump($upload_info);
```

Comment: Thanks... I did what you suggested but I get two errors in the last line... $this->db->insert('images', $insert_data) one saying "Message: Undefined property: Upload::$db " and another saying "Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object "

Comment: Ensure that the database class is loaded (either in the controller or in your config/autoload.php {in here $autoload[‘libraries’]}), the upload was successful, and that the $upload_info is being populated.

Answer (score 0):

For me, since most of my uploaded images are about the same thing (for example, product images) I might just store the filename (e.g. productshot1.jpg) in the database, since I know where it is anyway (for example, I might keep all product images in "/images/products/"). That way if you need to change something later, it's not so difficult.